# audioPlayers and file-picker issues with flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-audioplayers, flutter-file

hello. I'm trying this audioPlayers package but I didn't succeed to work it. I was following a youtube tutorial about it but half of the methods are changed. Flutter says there's no error in my code but I think I have logical errors. Since I don't know exactly what's async functions, perhaps I would make a mistake. So here is my code. MaterialApp widget is on main.dart file. But it's only one page. I hope you understand what I was trying to do.

https://gist.github.com/lawuysal/7a861e2865260897a3267d170ed61a11